# Place large image into a post to go full width of its container

Tags: images, uploads, responsive

I'd like to insert a huge infographics image into a post. The problem I'm facing with is that WordPress provides smaller versions of the image even though I choose "large" thus the image won't go full width of its container and smaller texts in the image are not readable.

In the image details, the `full size` option isn't the original full size, but smaller. I'd need an option for `960px` width.

[image: display settings]

These are the physical files created by WP:

[image]

`srcset`:

```
Infographic2-min-46x300.jpg 46w,
Infographic2-min-157x1024.jpg 157w,
Infographic2-min-768x4998.jpg 768w,
Infographic2-min-236x1536.jpg 236w,
Infographic2-min-315x2048.jpg 315w,
Infographic2-min-scaled.jpg 393w
```

`sizes`:

```
(max-width: 393px) 100vw, 393px
```

I noticed that WP uses `srcset` & `sizes` to make images responsive. Is it possible to override/customise it? Or how should these kind of large images be displayed?

Comment: I think "full" is the original image, not "large", although you can also give it pixel dimensions as an array. I'd guess you'd want to show something then click through to the original image if it's huge though?

Comment: Full is not original size, I've updated the post.

Comment: Are you using WordPress, or are you instead a WordPress.com customer?

Comment: I'm using WP, not a WP.com customer.

Comment: And is the original file `infographic2-min.jpg`? The full size is always the original image, iif you have optimisation plugins these can interfere with this. The canonical and official answer that will definitely answer your question on a stock standard install, is use the _full_ size image, but if the original image on the server is not the same as what you uploaded then something else is interfering

Comment: Yes, `infographic2-min.jpg` is the original file. No image manipulation/optimisation plugins are installed. `full size` won't display the original image but the `Infographic2-min-scaled.jpg`

Comment: Are you sure? You said in another question that a plugin had stopped working that offloaded images elsewhere. WP has no `scaled` image size, that is not standard WP behaviour

Comment: Just figured out as of WP 5.3 there's been a limitation introduced to image size, called `big_image_size_threshold`, more: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/373643/how-to-increase-media-image-scale-limit/373647#373647 After disabling it the max size of the image can be set.