# How to increase media image scale limit?

Tags: images, uploads, limit, scale

I'd like to insert a large infographics image into a post. The problem is that WordPress scales the image and applies a limit of 393px in my case.

When I try to manually increase it, a red exclamation mark shows up, and won't use the value given by me:

[image]

How to remove that limit?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution: It can be turned off:

```
add_filter( 'big_image_size_threshold', '__return_false' );
```

More: [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/big_image_size_threshold/)

Comment: Glad you found something that works for you. Generally speaking WP lets you scale down, but not up.